# Unity 'Netcode for GameObjects' Getting ClientID of most recently connected client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this custom spawn function to spawn player prefabs when a new client connects, but as it currently is programmed, it spawns a new prefab for the player but it doesn't transfer ownership from the server to the newly connected client. I'm trying to use the `player.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().SpawnWithOwnership();` function to spawn the new player prefab with the ownership set to the client, but to do so i need to pass the clientID as a parameter to the `SpawnWithOwnership()` function, the only problem is I'm not sure how to get the clientID as the `OnNetworkSpawn()` function that I'm using to spawn a prefab on client connect doesn't have any parameters such as `clientID`. I've tried looking through the API documentation for 'Netcode for GameObjects' but cannot find a function that would let me get the `clientID` i need.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class SpawnPlayer : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public GameObject playerPrefab;
    public float x, y, z;

    public override void OnNetworkSpawn(){
        if (!playerPrefab) return;
        Debug.Log("Called");
        Spawn();
    }

    void Spawn(){
        Debug.Log("Called 2");
        GameObject player = Instantiate(playerPrefab, new Vector3(x, y, z), Quaternion.identity);
        player.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().SpawnWithOwnership();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider changing the way you're getting the ClientID to the following approach. I tried making the same change myself and it seemed to work well. Just a suggestion!

```
public void TestServerRPC(ServerRpcParams serverRpcParams = default)
{
    var clientId = serverRpcParams.Receive.SenderClientId;
}
```